# How can I stop cocktails from being foamy?

Tags: cocktails

Whenever I make (shaken) clear cocktails, I end up with foam on top of the drink, like this:

[image]

I follow the usual steps of building the cocktail in the mixing tin, adding ice and shaking strongly for a few seconds. The ice comes from a regular freezer tray and isn't clear.

**How can I stop this from happening and get foam-less cocktails?**

Comment: @Kareen my bad, I didnt see that one.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'm going to undelete this and close as a dup. Doesn't cost you anything, and leaves breadcrumbs for others to find the existing question more easily.

Comment: @Jefromi Seems to me like its the exact same question, but sure, if it can help someone.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes, it is the same question, which is why it's marked as a duplicate. But since everyone phrases things differently, leaving the dups around makes it more likely that people manage to find the existing questions when they search, including the automatic mini-search that happens when you start to write a new question.